# Angular9 routing with modules

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular9

I created auth-routing.module.ts to include the modules of components I think I should include some thing but I don't know I should include for example compoents !! but it is included already in the modules of each module inside the components so what's wrong please ? what should I do?
with this code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth.component';

const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: "",
    component: AuthComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: "",
            redirectTo: "login",
            pathMatch: "full"
        },
        {
            path: "login",
            loadChildren: () =>
                import("./login/login.module").then(m => m.LoginModule)
        },
        {
            path: "reset-password",
            loadChildren: () =>
                import("./reset-password/reset-password.module").then(
                    m => m.ResetPasswordModule
                )
        },
        {
            path: "forget-password",
            loadChildren: () =>
                import("./forget-password/forget-password.module").then(
                    m => m.ForgetPasswordModule
                )
        }
    ]
}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule { }
```

and in the app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: "home",
  loadChildren: () =>
      import("./main/pages/home/home.module").then(
          m => m.HomeModule
      )
},
{
  path: "auth",
  loadChildren: () =>
      import("./main/pages/auth/auth.module").then(m => m.AuthModule)
},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Routing isn't working yet I don't know Why!!

Comment: Please let us know how you know it isn't working. What did you try and what was the result?

Comment: That is very obvious from the code you shared. - Tell us technical details so we can help you. What routes are you trying to access. Please update your original post with more details so we get a better picture of what is going on.

Comment: I created auth pages with modules like 
loginmodule included login component and then I call auth-routing.module.ts in the app-routing.module.ts same to forgetpassword module

Comment: you Know T think the problem is how to call routing module inside another routing module in angular 9

Comment: I Fiiiixed it , Yeaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah
the mistake was I should include in each module 
const routes = [
  {
      path: "",
      component: LoginComponent
  }
];

 and

RouterModule.forChild(routes) 
in imports